# implement Default for a templated struct where the only difference is the templated variable

Tags: templates, rust

After defining a matrix where the length templated so I can control the size easier:

```rust
pub struct SquareMatrix<const length: usize> {
    data: [[f32; length]; length],
}
```

I define default functions for the matrix:

```rust
impl Default for SquareMatrix<2> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        return SquareMatrix {
            data: [[0.0; 2];2],
        }
    }
}

impl Default for SquareMatrix<3> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        return SquareMatrix {
            data: [[0.0; 3];3],
        }
    }
}

impl Default for SquareMatrix<4> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        return SquareMatrix {
            data: [[0.0; 4];4],
        }
    }
}
```

It does not look elegant as the only difference of them is the length which is templated. But when I take out the `length` and define only 1 templated function:

```rust
impl Default for SquareMatrix<length> {
        fn default() -> Self {
        return SquareMatrix {
            data: [[0.0; length]; length],
        }
    }
}
```

Error prompt: `length not found in this scope`

Is there a way to define a templated function for templated struct?

Answer (score 3):

You are close, you just need to define the generic in the `Default` implementation:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct SquareMatrix<const LENGTH: usize> {
    data: [[f32; LENGTH]; LENGTH],
}

impl<const LENGTH: usize> Default for SquareMatrix<LENGTH> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        return SquareMatrix {
            data: [[0.0; LENGTH]; LENGTH],
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let matrix: SquareMatrix<2> = Default::default();

    println!("{:?}", matrix);
}
```

```
SquareMatrix { data: [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0]] }
```

Also, minor nitpick: const generics should be written in all caps.